# Flask Tutorial: KeyError: 'DATABASE'

Tags: python, flask, keyerror

I've have searched through and tried every solution to this problem that I could find I am still having issues with creating the database in the flask tutorial:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/dbinit/#tutorial-dbinit

The previous stackoverflow answers to this question centered around changing the path in DATABASE = ... or adding the actual flaskr.db file to the project file (although I am under the impression that sqlite3 should generate it automatically)

I'm using Cloud9 - which runs on ubuntu - so the original /tmp/flaskr.db path should work, yet it does not.

The contents of my project are:

```
/Flaskr
  /static
  /templates
  flaskr.db 
  flaskr.py
  schema.sql
```

The contents of flaskr.py:

```
# all the imports
import sqlite3
from contextlib import closing
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
 abort, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

For DATABASE = '' , I have also tried entering direct path:

```
DATABASE = '/home/ubuntu/workspace/flaskr/flaskr.db'
```

and (yes, I realize these are the same thing)

```
DATABASE = '/flaskr/flaskr.db'
```

I would also like to note that the flaskr.db file under the flaskr project was not originally there - but I added while I was troubleshooting to see if I could provide it's direct path.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "flaskr.py", line 28, in init_db
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
  File "flaskr.py", line 25, in connect_db
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
KeyError: 'DATABASE'
```

Again, I'm using Cloud9 runs on a Unix OS

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is that `Flask.config.from_envvar` is not finding your settings, because you have them here in `flaskr.py`.

You can use the `from_object` configuration method, as given in the Flask tutorial, like this:

```
app.config.from_object(__name__)
```

which would find your capitalized variable names as given. Or, if you wanted to continue using the `from_envvar` config, which is advisable since it keeps your database credentials out of revision control, [you can put those items into a `.cfg` file as documented here.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/):

Make a new file called `settings.cfg`:

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'
```

And remove those lines from `flaskr.py`. Then to start your app:

```
$ export FLASKR_SETTINGS=/path/to/settings.cfg
$ python flaskr.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a variable here:

```
DATABASE = '/tmp/flaskr.db'
```

...and then you are trying to read it from a different place:

```
sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
```

You can simply:

```
sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
```

or:

```
sqlite3.connect('/tmp/flaskr.db')
```